# For loop addition assignment for variables in post statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I declared multiple variables in a for loop, and I would like to increment my variables in the post statement. I understand this is not the best way to operate on multiple variables. But I'm curious to know why this never increments past 4.

```
for (let i1 = 0, i2 = 0; (i2 < s2.length) && (i1 < s1.length); i1, i2 = i1+4, i2+4) {
    console.log(i1, i2)
}
```

But this does.

```
for (let i1 = 0, i2 = 0; (i2 < s2.length) && (i1 < s1.length); i1, i2 = i1+=4, i2+=4) {
    console.log(i1, i2)
}
```

Comment: `i1, i2 = i1+4, i2+4` means `(i1), (i2 = i1 + 4), (i2 + 4)`, not `[i1, i2] = [i1 + 4, i2 + 4]`.

Comment: What @Ry- said. Just to explain further: `i1, i2 = i1+4, i2+4` is three statements, so your code says "1. Check the value if `i1` and discard it. 2. Set `i2` to the value of `i1 + 4`. 3. Compute the value of `i2 + 4` then discard it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It boils down to

```
i1, i2 = i1+4, i2+4
```

vs

```
i1, i2 = i1+=4, i2+=4
```

In both, you're using the comma operator, which evaluates each comma-separated value. Because the first `i1` isn't being used, you can drop those. Commas have the [lowest operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of all (1):

```
(i2 = i1+4), i2+4
```

vs

```
(i2 = i1+=4), i2+=4
```

The first code will assign `i2` to `i1+4` on each iteration, and then, in a separate expression, add 4 to `i2` *but do nothing with the result* - it goes unused.

The second code uses `+=` instead, so `i1 += 4` will both assign the result to `i1`, *and* it will evaluate to the new value, so

```
i2 = i1+=4
```

assigns the result to both `i1` and `i2`. (The `i2 += 4` then adds 4 to `i2` and assigns it to `i2`.

```js
for (let i1 = 0, i2 = 0; (i2 < 10) && (i1 < 10); i1, i2 = i1+=4, i2+=4) {
    console.log(i1, i2)
}
```

See how `i2` is assigned to *twice*. (is that really desirable?)